# Not able to find an API for getting BSE stock quote for my Android app

Tags: stock, stocks, stockquotes, google-finance-api

I searched 2days in google but still i am not able to get a proper API which i can use to get data.
I found one API

```
https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=w&q=BSE:YESBANK
```

which i am getting resonse data, but the data is not correct.
am i giving something wrong in `client=w` in above URL

Can anybody know any API for getting BSE data? even if it is a paid service i am k....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no free lunch here in the data segment. Since I had taken official feeds from NSE I can explain you to some extent.

1. You have to get into the datafeed agreement with NSE. And Realtime datafeed is quite costly as per year charges comes around 20 lakh per exchange + Service Taxes.
2. Per user fee will be applicable depends upon how you are planning to monetize the datafeed. Normally per use fee for NSE cash/futures segment is Rs360/user and first 300 users will be waived off.
3. You have to define your self as data vendor or data redistributor or you are planning to show the exchange data at free of cost.
4. You can lower you cost by getting the data from data redistributor(e.g globaldatafeeds) as normally your fee would be reduced by 20%. However still you have to get data vending agreement with NSE exchange. Without NSE permission you are not allowed to vend the data or redistribute the data even if you are doing at free of cost. Otherwise you will be tagged as  a illegal data vendor as per DOTEX
5. Only Data Redistributor (aka Authorized data vendors like globaldatafeeds, esignal, bloomberg...etc) develop their own api not the exchange itself.
6. However if you are looking for low cost options then you can prefer snapshot data or 15min delayed datafeeds. And the same above rules are applicable for most of the exchanges.

Comment: i dont understand exactly what u are trying to tell, may be bcz i am new to this stock words. can u tell me in simple words like,           If i want to develop a simple stock quote android application for free of cost, how much they charge(service available for least possible cost) and is the charge i have to pay yearly or at once. and tell me the site/vendor name where i can get for less cost

Comment: Can I use data-scraping technique from nse/bse websites? would that be illegal?

Comment: As Harshal said, to get real time and accurate feeds you need to reach data vendors.
For more information on BSE data visit https://www.bseindia.com/market_data_products.html

check for Data Subscription : vendors.

For pricing details: https://www.bseindia.com/downloads1/BSEInformationProductsPricingSheet.pdf